# StructureMap Use(Func<T>) - resolves only once

Tags: c#, structuremap

Iam using structure map for resolving my dependencies, however i have a rather special case where i want a dependency to be constructed through a method call.
This method shoudl be called everytime i cann GetInstance() however it only executes once.

My declaration looks like this:

```
x.For<UserService>().Use(c => { return MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance<UserService>(); });
```

is also tried

```
x.For<UserService>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use(c => { return MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance<UserService>(); });
```

which didnt change anything.
Does anyone know how i can make structuremap resolve every time ?

Comment: It sounds like the lifecycle you want is Unique Per Request. Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. I think the problem may be in your `MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance` method (which perhaps returns the same instance in successive calls) rather than here.

Here's a quick Unit Test I put together to mimic what you have (I just used System.Guid instead of your UserService), and which passes.

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<Guid>().Use(c => { return Guid.NewGuid(); });
        });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var o1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Guid>();
        var o2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Guid>();
        Assert.AreNotSame(o1, o2);
    }
```

**Side note**: You can simplify your syntax as follows:

```
x.For<UserService>().Use(() => MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance<UserService>());
```

And even

```
x.For<UserService>().Use(MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance<UserService>());
```

Comment: correct, it should work, however i used NLog to ensure that it wasnt the MultiObjectProvider that was failing, and my logs told me that the GetInstance method was called only once.

It is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: In your post it sounds like you are you explicitly calling GetInstance, is that correct? Because if you are not, then you will be getting one same instance per graph. See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/07/20/StructureMapPerRequestVsUniqueLifetimes.aspx

Comment: In which case this should do: `x.For<UserService>().LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()).Use(MultiObjectProvider.GetInstance<UserService>());`